# Rmarkdown problems witk 'knirt' in presentation

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, presentation

I am new here and I want to explain my problem.
I wrote the following code to install Rmarkdown (I have the packages in specific place in mi hard disk D)

```
.libPaths(c("D:/R_Packages", .libPaths()))
install.packages("rmarkdown",dependencies=TRUE)
install.packages("knitr", dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages("knitLatex",dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages("learnr")
install.packages('tinytex')
tinytex::install_tinytex()
library(knitr)
library(knitLatex)
library(learnr)
library(tinytex)
library(rmarkdown)
```

and almost all works good but when I tried with R presentation, in the windows of presentation said this:

```
Error in library(knitr) : there is no package called 'knitr'
Execution halted
```

If someone can help me to solve the problem I will appreciate it very much.

Comment: did `install.packages("knitr", dependencies = TRUE)` succeed?

Comment: Sorry for answer so late, but I can not solve the problem yet. I tried with your mention. Tise problem only happen with presentations (slide).